# Hiding specific html elements which are pulled in by script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a page and in there I have script that pulls in some more html, from that I wanna hide some of the elements.
Luckily I can use css

```
 <style>
      li.Item:nth-child(1),
      li.Item:nth-child(2) {
        display: none;
      }
 </style>
```

But this is very crude way of doing it and might backfire. What I wanted was to use jquery and hide it when it contains something I dont want to display. yet even on document ready. I can't target it presumably because the html loads later than doc.ready.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Put the code that hides the relevant elements right after the code that appends them - note that if they're added asynchronously, you'll need to use the callback provided. It would be a much better idea to do this in CSS though. I'm sure theres a way to make it work as you need

Comment: Add how you get the HTML code. Is it an ajax call?

Comment: You could add an extra class which hides those items you don't want to show. If the content is "top secret", you shouldn't load it in the first place, untill the conditions to show the content are fullfilled.

Comment: add html code and what html code pulled by JS

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I put the hide script right after but it fires too early not catching anything. Thusitha it's an ajax. I can't add classses to which I can't target anyway. And it's best for it work without flickering like showing all of it for split second and then only what I wanted to show.

Comment: What you mean you "can't target a class"? If you can target the items in a stylesheet, you can target them in a script as well. Also, it is possible to not add the items to the DOM, store them in a variable, and add to the DOM when they can be shown. There should be no flickering when using classes, though. It's hard to give more specific answer without seeing the code, which adds the elements and some example of the elements.

Comment: @Teemu script loads the html even later than doc.ready. I cant modify the script html classses manually.

Comment: Why not? In the question you say you want "_to use jquery and hide [some elements]_". Please show the code at hands ...

Comment: `I put the hide script right after but it fires too early not catching anything. Thusitha it's an ajax.` Then you need to use the callback, as I mentioned in the previous comment

Comment: @Teemu console.log(jQuery(".Item")); when I have this in doc ready after the script that pulls in html, it shows empty in consolelog but when I paste the same thing in the console log it will show all the items.

Comment: "_Thusitha it's an ajax_" Yes, we definitely know how AJAX works, and I assume you know it too, since you get some elements appened to the DOM ... If you really need help with this, you post the callback code and an example of the AJAX response ...